# Возможность выбора локализации вручную C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Есть текущая версия локализации с папками values и файлами string.xml. Все по оф. рекомендациям.

А как сделать выбор языка через настройки приложения? Допустим пользователь с английским языком устройства захочет изменить язык на испанский. 
Как заставить приложение использовать выбранную локаль value_es/string.xml?

Comment: В своём проекте я использовал Plugin.Multilingual: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Multilingual/

Comment: @Emigrant у меня другая реализация и плагин не подойдет. Надо просто заставить приложение "поверить", что на телефон другой язык.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на англоязычном stackoverflow.

Вот код, заставляющий приложение менять Локаль.

```
using Android.Util;
using Java.Util;      
//
  Android.Content.Res.Resources res = this.Resources;
            DisplayMetrics Dm = res.DisplayMetrics;
            Android.Content.Res.Configuration conf = res.Configuration;
            if (LanguageCodevalue != null)
            {
                conf.SetLocale(new Locale(LanguageCodevalue));
            }
            else
            {
                conf.SetLocale(new Locale("en"));
            }
            res.UpdateConfiguration(conf, Dm);
            this.Recreate();
```